# How can I select network inside a geo data frame boundary

Tags: plot, graph, osmnx

The shape of gdf is as below:

[image]

I want to find the network inside this gdf,

`G = ox.graph_from(..., networktype="drive")`

I want the result be something like this

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the network inside this gdf?" What's the code snippet referring to?

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I want to get the graph like the grey graph in the above photo, the point is that by using `G=ox.graph_from_place` or `G=ox.graph_from_point` I can not get this graph, since it is a union of many places, but I have the data of geo data frame boundary of green region, is there any way by having the boundary we can get the graph? something like `G=graph_from_boundary` ?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I believe you can clip the network just as a geodataframe with `gdf_clipped = gdf.clip(mask, keep_geom_type=True)`. Take a look here: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.clip.html